# AWS EKS User "system:node:ip-192-168-185-224.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "xxx"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, rbac

I am using AWS EKS to deploy an application. I wish to run a cronjob in a Pod to create Job resources periodically.

However, when I exec into a Pod and run `kubectl get job`, it returns me `Error from server (Forbidden): jobs.batch is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-192-168-185-224.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal" cannot list resource "jobs" in API group "batch" in the namespace "xxx"`

When I run `kubectl get job` inside the same Pod, it will show all the Pod I created in the same namespace.

I am wondering if the RBAC is not configured correctly. I created a `ClusterRole`, as shown below

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: job-admin
rules:
- apiGroups: ["batch", "extensions"]
  resources: ["jobs"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

And after I created the ClusterRole, I created a ClusterRoleBinding by running:

```sh
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-job-admin --clusterrole=job-admin --user=system:node
```

However, it does not work, I could not run `kubectl get jobs` in the Pod. Any solutions to this?

Comment: It looks like the user that is used when you're trying to perform this operation isn't `"system:node"` but `"system:node:ip-192-168-185-224.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"`. Could you try to set it up in your `ClusterRoleBinding` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me which pod works and which doesn't but, did you associate a ServiceAccount to the pod? You should ideally 1) create a SA, bind the role to the SA and assign the SA to the pod. [This](https://betterprogramming.pub/k8s-tips-using-a-serviceaccount-801c433d0023) is one of the many examples that walk you through this.

Comment: @mario Hi, since the system:node:ip-192-168-185-224.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal is just a node inside the cluster, I wish the cluster role binding for all the nodes inside a cluster, not a particular node. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: As mreferre suggested, your `Pod` should use some [`ServiceAccount`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) so it can make API calls. Do you have any defined at the moment ? You say about the `ClusterRole` and the `ClusterRoleBinding` you created but what was actually the reason of associating it with `--user=system:node` ? As already suggested, create a new `SA` for your `Pod` and you should be fine.